# Excel: take the same column from every worksheet and add to new worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel workbook with 500 worksheets. An example worksheet is shown in the image below. I am only interested in the data in column `E` of every one of these 500 sheets.

Is there an easy way for me to take column `E` from every worksheet and put them in a new worksheet?

I don't want to do any calculations on them, just display all 500 column Es in a new worksheet.

I've been googling and can't find a solution.

Format of the worksheets:

[image: Format of worksheets]

Comment: In each column of the new worksheet, point to E1 of a different worksheet.  Then copy the row down.  If there's logic to the sheet names, you might be able to do it in one formula.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished relatively easily using VBA.

- Open the Visual Basic IDE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Insert a new public module using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>
- Paste the following code into the module:

  ```
  Sub GrabColumnE()
      Dim shtCoE As Worksheet
      Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
      Dim lngCol As Long: lngCol = 1

      Set shtCoE = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
      For Each shtSrc In Sheets
          If Not shtSrc Is shtCoE Then
              shtSrc.Columns(5).Copy shtCoE.Columns(lngCol)
              lngCol = 1 + lngCol
          End If
      Next shtSrc
  End Sub
  ```
- Either press <kbd>F5</kbd> with the cursor within the code to run the Sub, or go to the `Developer` tab on the ribbon, click on `Macros`, select the macro with the above name and click `Run`.

I hope this helps.